# Bash: How to generate random float number using $RANDOM

Tags: bash, shell, random, printf, numeric-data

Is it possible to generate real random numbers with a specific precision and in a specific range using the Integer Random Generator $RANDOM? 
For example how we can generate real number with 4 precision between 0 and 1?

```
0.1234
0.0309
0.9001
0.0000
1.0000
```

A simple workaround:

```
printf "%d04.%d04\n" $RANDOM $RANDOM
```

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "real random numbers". Are you requiring a source of random numbers generated by something like particle decay, or will you be happy with a pseudo-random generator? Is your application of these numbers of cryptographic or scientific significance, or do you just want something that "looks random".

Comment: ... or do you actually mean "float" or "floating point number?

Comment: Thank you for comment. I need a pseudo random number generator for floating point numbers based on $RANDOM.

Comment: ...for implementing meta heuristic algorithms in bash.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
awk -v n=10 -v seed="$RANDOM" 'BEGIN { srand(seed); for (i=0; i<n; ++i) printf("%.4f\n", rand()) }'
```

This will output `n` random numbers (ten in the example) in the range [0,1) with four decimal digits. It uses the `rand()` function in `awk` (not in standard `awk` but implemented by most common `awk` implementations) which returns a random value in that range.  The random number generator is seeded by the shell's `$RANDOM` variable.

When an `awk` program only has `BEGIN` blocks (and no other code blocks), `awk` will not try to read input from its standard input stream.

On any OpenBSD system (or system that has the same [`jot` utility](http://man.openbsd.org/jot), originally in 4.2BSD), the following will generate 10 random number as specified:

```
jot -p 4 -r 10 0 1
```

Comment: Really strictly speaking, since the output of `rand()` is a float within [0,1), it probably isn't exactly evenly distributed when rounded off to four decimal digits. It would be, if the float were of infinite precision, but it isn't: it's likely to be generated from random bits, so there are 2^N different values, and they don't map uniformly to a set of 1000 values. But as long as those pseudo-random floats have enough bits, and you're not doing anything really exact, you probably won't notice.

Answer (score 10):

As pointed out in another answer, there are other utilities that you can use to generate random numbers.  In this answer, I limit my resources to `$RANDOM`, and a few basic arithmetic functions.

For floating point numbers, try something like

```
printf '%s\n' $(echo "scale=8; $RANDOM/32768" | bc )
```

That will get you the best precision because `$RANDOM` only generates numbers between 0 and 32767. (including 32767!)  But, I've also broken my rule about using basic arithmetic functions by invoking `bc`.

But before moving on, I'd like to look at two issues *precision* and *range* for floating point numbers.  After that, I will look at generating a range of integers (and if you can generate integers, you can later divide them to get a decimal if you wish using whatever utilities you prefer to accomplish that.)

**Precision**

Taking the approach of `$RANDOM/32768`, since `$RANDOM` generates values from 0 to 32767, the result of `$RANDOM/32768` will likewise be finitely many values.  In other words, it's still a discrete random variable (and with a computer you'll never be able to get away from that fact).  With that in mind, then you can accomplish some degree of *precision* by using `printf`.

If you want a finer covering of the interval,  you could start thinking in base 32768. So, in theory `$RANDOM + $RANDOM*32768` should give you a uniform distribution between 0 and 1,073,741,823.  But, I'm doubtful the command line will handle that precision very well.  A couple points relating to this particular case:

- The sum of two independent, uniformly distributed random variables in not generally uniform.  In this case, at least theoretically speaking (see third point), they are.
- Don't think you can simplify `$RANDOM + $RANDOM*32768 = $RANDOM * ( 1 + 32768 )`.  The two occurrences of `$RANDOM` are really two different events.
- I don't know enough about how `$RANDOM` is generated to know whether calling it twice like this will truly generate two independent random events.

**Range**

Let's consider just `$RANDOM/32768`.  If you want a number in a range, say `[a,b)`, then

```
$RANDOM/32768*(b-a) + a
```

will land you in the desired range.

**Generation of integer values**

First, consider generating random numbers between `[0,b)` where `b` is less than `32768`.  Consider the product `q*b`, where `q` is the integer part of `32768/b`.  Then what you can do is generate random number between 0 and 32767, but throw out those which are greater than or equal to `q*b`.  Call the number thus generated `G`.  Then `G` will fall in the range of 0 to `q*b`, and its distribution will be uniform.  Now, apply modular arithmetic to get this value whittled down into the desired range:

```
G % b
```

Note, randomly generating a number as follows

```
$RANDOM % b
```

will not create a uniform distribution, unless `b` just happens to be one of the divisors of `32768`.

**Writing a bash script for this**

Calculating `q*b` as described above sounds like a pain.  But it really isn't.  You can get it as follows:

```
q*b = 32768 - ( 32768 % b )
```

In Bash, you can get this with

```
$((32768 - $((32768 % b)) ))
```

The following code will generate a random number in the range `0..b` (not inclusive of `b`).  `b=$1`

```
m=$((32768 - $((32768 % $1)) ))
a=$RANDOM
while (( $a > $m )); 
do
    a=$RANDOM
done
a=$(($a % $1))
printf "$a\n"
```

**Addendum**

Technically, there's little reason to work with

```
m=$((32768 - $((32768 % $1)) ))
```

The following will accomplish the same thing

```
a=$RANDOM
while (( $a > $1 )); 
do
    a=$RANDOM
done
printf "$a\n"
```

It's a lot more work, but computers are fast.

**Generating an Integer in a larger range**

I'll let you figure this out.  Care needs to be taken, and at some point you'll have to take into consideration the memory limitations of the computer in handling arithmetic operations.

**Final note**

The accepted answer will not create a random number uniformly over 0 to 1.

To see this, 
try the following

```
$ for i in {1..1000}; do echo .$RANDOM; done | awk '{ a += $1 } END { print a }'
```

For a truly uniform distribution over `[0,1)` you should be seeing an average of close to `0.500`.

But as you can see by running the above snippet, you will instead get something like `314.432` or `322.619`. Since it's 1000 numbers, the average of this is `.322`.  The true average for this sequence of generated numbers is `.316362`

You can obtain this true average using the perl script

```
  perl -e '{ $i=0;  
             $s=0; 
             while ( $i<=32767 ) 
               { 
                 $j = sprintf "%.5f", ".$i"; 
                 $j =~ s/^0\.//; 
                 print "$j\n"; 
                 $s += $j; 
                 $i++ 
               }; 
             printf "%.5f\n", $s/32767; 
           }'
```

I'm adding integers here to help you see how this approach of using `.$RANDOM` isn't doing what you most likely want it to do.  In other words, think about which integers are being generated and which ones are missed altogether.  Quite a large number are skipped; quite a few are doubled.

Answer (score 7):

On systems where shell's printf is able to understand the `%a` format (bash ksh zsh , etc.) and therefore is able to perform an internal base change (hex -> dec) (uniform in `[0,1)` range from 0.00003 to 0.99997):

```
printf '%.5f\n' "$(printf '0x0.%04xp1' $RANDOM)"
```

You could even use more digits by combining more calls to `$RANDOM` (from 0.000000001 to 0.999999999)

```
printf '%.9f\n'  "$(printf '0x0.%08xp2' $(( ($RANDOM<<15) + $RANDOM )))"
```

The internal (to the shell) "$RANDOM" algorithm is based in a linear-feedback shift register (LFSR). Those are not Cryptographically Secure Pseudo Random Number Generators (CSPRNGs). A better option is to use bytes from the `/dev/urandom` device. That will require the call to external octal or hex dump.

```
$ printf '%.19f\n' "0x0.$(od -N 8 -An -tx1 /dev/urandom | tr -d ' ')"
0.7532810412812978029

$ printf '%.19f\n' "0x0.$(hexdump -n 8 -v -e '"%02x"' /dev/urandom)"
0.9453460825607180595
```

---

A very simple (but non-uniform) solution to get a float is:

```
printf '0.%04d\n' $RANDOM
```

A way to make it uniform in the range `[0,1)` (not including 1):

```
while a=$RANDOM; ((a>29999)); do :; done; printf '0.%04d\n' "$((a%10000))"
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `$(( ( RANDOM % N )  + MIN ))`

Replace `N` with MAX number and MIN with minimum number you want to generate.(`N` as MAX is exclusive, put `N+1` to have both MAX, MIN inclusive).

Or you can use `$(shuf -i MIN-MAX -n 1)` instead.

from [`man shuf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/shuf.1.html):

```
-i, --input-range=LO-HI
    treat each number LO through HI as an input line
-n, --head-count=COUNT 
    output at most COUNT lines
```

The `-n 1` in `shuf` here means only generate one random Number.

This will generate random numbers between *0~9999* with leading zeros using `printf` (in result, number **1** is exclusive).

```
printf "0.%04d\n" $(( RANDOM % 1000 ))
0.0215
```

Comment: This also will not produce a true random number in the given range except in the case where N is a divisor of 32767 (the upper limit of $RANDOM).

Answer (score 2):

On bash

```
bc -l <<< "scale=4 ; $((RANDOM % 10000 ))/10000"
```

where `1/10000` is your random precision and `4` digits your output precision

Comment: When I re-run this I get the same answer over and over again. Any idea why that happens? If I just `echo $RANDOM` I get different results.

Comment: I'm retring now and it works for me

Comment: Oh odd. I wonder if I accidentally assigned it or something. A fresh shell session works works.

Answer (score 1):

`zsh` has a `rand48()` arithmetic function (wrapper to the `erand48()` standard function) in its `zsh/mathfunc` module:

```
zmodload zsh/mathfunc
printf '%.4f\n' $((rand48()))
```

While `$RANDOM` is 15 bits, pseudo-random and reproducible, `bash` 5.1+ has a safer 32 bit integer `$SRANDOM`, based on truly random sources where available. It doesn't support floating point arithmetic, but at least you can use it to seed `awk`'s pseudo random generator (which otherwise by default uses the very predictable result of `time()`):

```
echo "$SRANDOM" | awk '
  {
    srand($1)
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
      printf "%.4f\n", rand()
  }'
```

(bear in mind it's still only 32 bits of entropy, and `awk` does deterministic pseudo-random generation based on that seed)